# Display text field at the bottom of the page on change of group Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, conditional-statements, suppress

I'm using Crystal Reports 14. I'm upgrading reports from an old company software (but very powerful) using oracle report builder.  I have a report which is grouped by agency, and at the end of the group, at the bottom of the page, i need to display a static text field with the details of the director of each agency (These reports are printed and signed at the end from the director of each agency)

I have tried several methods, such as putting the text fields on group footer, but i have enabled the option new page before on group footer, because i don't want two agencies on the same page. But this creates several layout problems too, so it's an option.

The other method i tried is to put it on the page footer, but how i can conditional suppress it, so that it is displayed ONLY at the end of the group? Is there any way to have a dammy field (like a flag) when the group is changed so i can suppress the fields on that condition?

I hope i have give all information and be as clear as i could. Excuse me in advance but I need a solution ASAP.

Comment: Can you enable option new page after for the group footer and place your constant field in group footer

Comment: Greetings Silva, New page after is not an option due to design limitations, but i found a solution. I have managed to validate when the current page is the end of the group, by creating a formula that compare two values and return a static value (i use it as a flag). Depending on that flag i suppress the text fields on all the other pages, so it works pretty well. Thank you for your time